# Python: Need to output to a file based on 2 or more matches in a text string

Tags: python, scripting

I'm new to Python and am trying to find a way to write to a file based on two conditions of a text file:

1. Out of a given text, one of the lines must match my search exactly. Position and value is always the same.
2. If condition one above is met and a value of X (to be defined \ can change) is also present in the text at a known location, print both the matching text from condition one and the value X with the 10 immediate proceeding characters which never change.

So from the text given in another example I saw on this site:

```
textInput = """\
I'm trying to have my program grab every fifth word from a text file and
place it in a single string. For instance, if I typed "Everyone likes to
eat pie because it tastes so good plus it comes in many varieties such
as blueberry strawberry and lime" then the program should print out
"Everyone because plus varieties and." I must start with the very first
word and grab every fifth word after. I'm confused on how to do this.
Below is my code, everything runs fine except the last 5 lines."""
```

From this example, I would like to write to a file the following but only if both are present:

```
"place it in a single string. For instance, if I typed "Everyone likes to"
```

and

`"blueberry strawberry and lime"`.

The word lime may change to an unknown, varying value.

What it comes down to is that I have a bunch of log files I'm going through. If an IP address is present at a particular location in the file, I want that IP (which is unknown), the 10 proceeding characters along with with a string of text that is always present a few lines up from the IP. Both of these are to be written to a file.

I figured out how open \ close files and write entries etc. to a new file for a particular found phrase but am having problems sending entries to a file if a specific combination of two or more conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to read a log file, then use regular expressions to find all ip addresses in your log.

```
ip = re.compile("^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$")
ip = re.findall(ip, yourLogFile)
```

then you would use os to loop through each file in your folder of ip's already on file

```
import os

ipAlreadyOnFile = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\yourDirectory'):
    for file in files:
        ipAlreadyOnFile.append(file)
```

then you could find the differences between the two lists:

```
newIp = list(set(ip) - set(ipAlreadyOnFile))
```

now your newIp list has nothing but new ip addresses to either add to your directory or do something else with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Chris but it doesn't quite solve my problem. I have logs with hundreds of entries. Each entry consists of 18 lines. Each line ends with a carriage return and consists of words and numbers. A subset of those entries has an IP address associated with them. I'm trying to find those entries with the IP along with another associated condition that is indicated at a different spot in the entry. Comparing the log file to other log files doesn't get me the info I need.